# Adding large Redux code base to React Native / Unable to resolve module error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, node-modules

Has anyone else had problems adding a large redux code base to their RN projects? Redux was originally created for react web. When I comment out the redux imports in my RN app, it works fine. When I uncomment them out I get a red screen with the "Unable to resolve module" error.

I've searched this error message and seen suggestions online, but none of them work for me so I'm making this post. I'm reset watchman, killed extra processes running, reinstalled my node_modules many times and nothing seems to work.

This makes me wonder if it is possible to have something inside redux that might only work for the web and not mobile. Can redux include something RN compile can't understand?

Has anyone else encountered this or have any ideas?

Comment: Are you importing a module named `promise` somewhere? Please share source code. Redux is just some javascript codes which should work on both web and mobile. I also had a complicated app without redux, and just changed the structure to use redux without any problems.

Are you trying to use Promises in javascript? what is `promise`? a RN module?

Comment: Can you post full stack trace?

Comment: @agent_hunt I posted image of error. I'm not sure what the promise is here, but it references ducks that are causing the issue when I import.

Comment: @Ataomega right, redux should theoretically just work out of the box for RN, but see image above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: A duck requires react-intl and a file using react-int is Embedded JavaScript (.ejs) so that doesn't compile well with react native. Not sure how to fix it yet, but that is causing the problem.